# How do you make an R coded program running on AWS accessible from your website?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, web

In the creation of a simulation for our company, we coded the entire thing in R. It runs on AWS, and the consumers have been given links that route to the AWS page. Our website, however, is currently running off of Wordpress. In order for our customers to be able to access the product, we need to find a way to connect the product to the website. We would hence like to replace the current site with a new one that allows users to access our simulation from the website.

The only option we’ve come up with is to create a separate domain that has the interface built into the R program, and have a link to that domain from the current website. However, we would prefer to have a more direct solution.

Do any of you have any suggestions as to how we might achieve this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: If my answer was of help, please mark it as an accepted answer. If not, feel free to comment what you feel is missing and I will add it!

Answer (score 1):

This answer very much depends on your code, but I think you have several options.

**Run on external website**

Pros: 
Full control over code, easy to update without risking changes to main site
Easily accessible either by directly linking to it, or using `<iframe>` (HTML) on your main website, no Wordpress support required!

Cons:
Separate domain, some extra costs (?)

**Shinyapps.io**

Pros: 
Easily publishable, often free

Cons: 
Available for mostly everyone, which might not be ideal in a business situation
Less control over the platform

EDIT: I wanted to add that you can host your own shiny applications, and build the [front-end using HTML](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-tags.html). This gives you some more control.

**AWS**

Pros:

You should be able to set up an instance where the simulation is run on a subdomain that is not directly tied to Wordpress, e.g. outside of the main Wordpress folder.

As I said, the ideal solution depends on your code. Does it take user input, does it need to save files often? What kind of access control do you need?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was helpful! We did use shiny apps in the past, but it isn’t as customizable as we need it to be. We need to find something that can replace shiny as a front-end tool (java?). 

We have different users who will interact with the website and perform tasks, such as buying inventory. What would be the most efficient way to store user interactions/data? Do we need to add a SQL database on AWS or would you recommend a different approach? 

Currently, we don’t have too much data coming from the users.

Comment: Shiny does support HTML/CSS/Javascript, making it very customizable. It takes some getting used to, but it is doable. An alternative that I have only considered theoretically would be to make a frontend in normal HTML with a Node.js backend, which parses data to and from the R simulation. In general, I think this very much depends on your applications use case and requirements, which I know too little about.

Your R simulation should be separate from your other website uses, such as buying inventory, saving user interactions, etc. However, there are options to connect to databases using R.